# Does Entity Framework currently support custom functions in the Where clause?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Entity Framework currently supports table valued functions and custom functions defined in the SSDL, but I can't find any example of it being used as a criteria, in the `where` clause.

Example:

```
var query = this.db.People;
query = query.Where(p => FullText.ContainsInName(p.Id, "George"));
```

In this example, `ContainsInName` is my custom function that I want to be executed in the `where` clause of the query.

Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

It won't support a function like that.  That said, if you're just trying to see if `p.Id` is inside some string you send in, you can do this:

`query.Where(p => "George".Contains(p.Id));`

Note that `String.Contains` takes in a `string` or `char` to compare.  If `p.Id` is an `int`, you can do this:

`query.Where(p => "George".Contains(p.Id.ToString()));`

That will run the query at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out your schema namespace. Open .edmx in XML editor and you will find something like this at the top

   ```
   `<Schema Namespace="My.Project.Name.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas...
   ```
2. Import your functions into schema.
3. Create a static class with static functions

   ```
   public static class FullText
   {
       [EdmFunction("My.Project.Name.Store", "ContainsInName")]
       public static bool ContainsInName(int Id, string Name)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException("You can only call this method as part of a LINQ expression");
       }
   }
   ```

Then use it like in your example :)

Not sure about using table-valued functions in `where` clause.